# How to dynamically change the type of an input field in ionic2/Angular2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to implement a password field with a reveal option

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label color="dark" fixed>Mot De Passe</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="password"></ion-input>
  <ion-icon
      [name]="isActive?'eye':'eye-off'"
      item-right
      (click)="isActive=!isActive;"
      isActive=true>
 </ion-icon>
</ion-item>
```

So, I can change the icon but I can't figure out how to toggle the type of the password field !!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have a few options

**Interpolation**

```
<ion-input type="{{ isActive ? 'password' : 'text' }}"></ion-input>
```

or

**Property Binding**

```
<ion-input [type]="isActive ? 'password' : 'text'"></ion-input>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Property binding](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#property-binding) to pass a string such as 'text' or 'password' value to the `type` attribute of the input element:

```
export class SomePage {
    type: string = "text";
    isActive: Boolean = false; 

    constructor() {}

    getType() {
        return isActive ? 'password' : 'text';
    }

    setType() {
        this.type = isActive ? 'password' : 'text';
    }
}

<ion-item>
  <ion-label color="dark" fixed>Mot De Passe</ion-label>
  <ion-input [type]="type"></ion-input>
  <ion-input [type]="getType()"></ion-input>
  <ion-icon
      [name]="isActive ? 'eye' : 'eye-off'"
      item-right
      (click)="isActive = !isActive;"
      isActive=true>
 </ion-icon>
</ion-item>
```

You can change the value to however you would need either through the ternary statements you are using `isActive ? 'password':'text'` or perhaps a method that sets the string value to move the logic out of the template and into the controller.

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MpPKSxuid998Q4ixd5t6?p=preview) demonstrating the functionality showing both setting equal to a class string property and ternary statement.

Answer (score 0):

HTML File :

```
<input type="{{isPassword ? 'password' : 'text' }}">
<button type="button" (click)="show()">show password</button>
```

TS File :

```
isPassword = true;
show() {
    this.isPassword = !(this.isPassword);
}
```